# Git problems with empty repo

Tags: git

I got an account for a new project to a remote git server that i dont have any access. (I have zero experience with GIT) 
It appears that it is empty.

1. Trying clone from netbeans i get **can not open 'git-upload-pack'**
2. Trying manually with MING32 i get that i am trying to clone an empty repository (it is empty)
3. Trying to push a hello world project i get "refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master"

Is there anything i can do provided i dont have any other access ?
I tried many things but nothing helped. Most articles required access at remote repo

Comment: You should probably drop by the #git channel on freenode. Those guys are really helpful.

Comment: I agree with @Alexander. It sounds like you have a few separate issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by ssl verify thing. I had to deactivate it..

Answer (score 1):

(2) is caused by the repo being empty. The message stating so is not an error, it's just a notification (cloning an empty repository is perfectly legit).

(3) is caused because the remote repository is not a "bare" repository - that is, it has a working copy, and that working copy has `master` checked out. It sounds like whoever set up your remote repository probably should have created it as a bare repo - you might ask them to re-create it as such.